# HashMap returning null after adding values

Tags: java, hashmap

I know this question has been asked before but I can't understand how to fix this issue. I'm adding values to a HashMap and in **setStudent** and then when I try to change the value in **replaceName** but the key doesn't seem to exist.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Student {

    private HashMap<String, List<String>> studentDetails = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> studentModules = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    public void setStudent(String id, String name, String postalAddress, String emailAddress, String degreeTitle, String dateEnrolled, List<String> modules) {
        List<String> information = new ArrayList<>();
        information.add(name);
        information.add(postalAddress);
        information.add(emailAddress);
        information.add(degreeTitle);
        information.add(dateEnrolled);
        studentDetails.put(id, information);
        studentModules.put(id, modules);
    }

    public List<String> getStudentDetails(String x) {
        return studentDetails.get(x);
    }

    public List<String> getStudentModules(String x) {
        return studentModules.get(x);
    }

    public void replaceName(String id, String name, String postalAddress, String emailAddress, String degreeTitle, String dateEnrolled) {

        List<String> information = new ArrayList<>();
        information.add(name);
        information.add(postalAddress);
        information.add(emailAddress);
        information.add(degreeTitle);
        information.add(dateEnrolled);
        studentDetails.replace(id, information);
    }
}
```

My main class is quite long but basically it takes user input to get the values:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner source = new Scanner(System.in);
        RecordManager r = new RecordManager();
        Module m = new Module();
        Student s = new Student();
        ChangeName c = new ChangeName();

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the student id:");
            r.setId(source.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Please enter the student name:");
            r.setName(source.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Please enter the student address:");
            r.setAddress(source.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Please enter the student email address:");
            r.setEmailAddress(source.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Please enter the degree title:");
            r.setDegreeTitle(source.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Please enter the date enrolled:");
            r.setDateEnrolled(source.nextLine());

            List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the module name:");
                String name = source.nextLine();
                m.setName(name);
                a = r.addModule(name, a);
                m.setTitle(name);

                System.out.println("Please enter the module code:");
                m.setCode(source.nextLine());

                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter the module mark (between 1 and 100):");
                    int mark = source.nextInt();
                    if (mark > 0 && mark <101) {
                        m.setMark(mark);
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Module mark must be between 1 and 100");
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Please enter the module credits:");
                m.setCredits(source.nextInt());

                m.setModule();

                System.out.println("Would you like to enter another module? (Y/N)");
                String more = source.next();
                if (more.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                    break;
                }
                source.nextLine();
            }
            r.setModules(a);
            s.setStudent(r.getId(), r.getName(), r.getAddress(), r.getEmailAddress(), r.getDegreeTitle(), r.getDateEnrolled(), r.getModules());     
            r.addStudents(r.getId(), s.getStudentDetails(r.getId()));

            System.out.println("Would you like to enter the details for another student? (Y/N)");
            String another = source.next();
            if (another.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                break;
            }
            source.nextLine();
        }
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Full list of students and details (1) \nLookup a student by name (2) \nChange student name (3)");
            source.nextLine();
            int choice = source.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1) {
                for (String id : r.getStudents().keySet()) {
                    System.out.println(s.getStudentDetails(id) + " " + s.getStudentModules(id));
                }
                break;
            }
            else if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the full name of the student:");
                source.nextLine();
                String name = source.nextLine();
                boolean exists = false;
                int i = 0;
                for (String id : r.getStudents().keySet()) {
                    if (s.getStudentDetails(id).get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                        System.out.println(s.getStudentDetails(id) + " " + s.getStudentModules(id));
                        exists = true;
                    }
                    i += 1;     
                }
                if (exists == false) {
                    System.out.println("Student not found");
                }
                break;
            }
            else if (choice == 3) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the ID of the student:");
                source.nextLine();
                String id = source.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter the new name:");
                String name = source.nextLine();
                c.changeName(id, name, s.getStudentDetails(id));
                System.out.println(s.getStudentDetails(id));
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect selection. Please enter 1, 2 or 3");
            }               
        }       
    }
}
```

And finally I have the class to change the name:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ChangeName {

    RecordManager r = new RecordManager();
    Student s = new Student();

    public void changeName(String id, String newName, List<String> details) {
        s.replaceName(id, newName, details.get(1), details.get(2), details.get(3), details.get(4)); 
    }   

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: How do you use `Student` class?

Comment: Could you edit this to include a main method or whatever code you are using this Student class in?

Comment: Its quite long but I've added it now, thanks :)

Comment: To assist in helping you consider submitting a modified class without the input prompts but with a data structure populated with the appropriate values.

Comment: Ok so i see the problem is your ChangeName class. This uses a new instance of the Student class where as you have your own instance of Student class defined on your main method that loads the initial data to the hash map. In order to get to that you will have to pass the student class you initialise in your main method, into the ChangeName class as a constructor parameter. Note : This is not the optimal way to do it, but I just wanted to help you get this working with what you have right now.